# how to run CLI from root with user hdfs

Tags: linux, shell-script, hadoop

when I run the following cli from hdfs user its running well

```
    # su hdfs
    $ hadoop fs -du -s /home/test/* | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
     4182692
```

but when I run it from root , while using su -l hdfs then I get

```
su -l hdfs -c " hadoop fs -du -s /home/test/* | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' "
awk: cmd. line:1: { sum +=  } END { print sum }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
^C
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
```

when I am wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command which need to be executed as `hdfs` is shorter. Thy something like:

```
su -l hdfs -c "hadoop fs -du -s /home/test/*" | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

And better use `sudo` for this purpose:

```
sudo -u hdfs "hadoop fs -du -s /home/test/*" | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```